# AWS RDS save snapshot of selected tables

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snapshot, boto3, rds

I'm trying to save a snapshot of several tables programatically in python, instead of all DB.

I couldn't find the API (in boto/boto3) to do that.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Just to clarify the question. You want to export a subset of the tables in your database, but you can only find the API calls to export the entire database?

Comment: "Snapshot" is not a good term here. "Backup" or "dump" is better. If you are running MySQL, MariaDB or Aurora RDS, simple `mysqldump` would do the trick. Not a boto3 solution, but you can call `mysqldump` from a Python script.

Comment: "Just to clarify the question. You want to export a subset of the tables in your database, but you can only find the API calls to export the entire database?"  that was my intention

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using the AWS RDS snapshot mechanism, and it isn't possible using the AWS SDK. It is possible using the API for the specific database engine you are using. You would need to specify what database you are using for further help.

Comment: How is that possible using the API? I've looked at boto3 documentation for RDS but found no function that can do this.

Comment: I feel like I tried to specify very clearly in my answer that you cannot do that using one of the AWS SDKs like boto3.  You have to use something like `mysqldump` or `pgdump` or whatever is appropriate for the specific database engine you are using.